# Import directory structure into a data structure to allow additional fields

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, directory-structure

In the application we are building, a folder has a piece of data that needs to be associated with it called 'folder role'. Based on the folder role, I will be displaying all files associated with a particular role in a web page. I strongly suspect that further development will lead to additional requirements for what I'm calling metadata associated with an entire file system.

This question isn't so much about how to walk the directory and grab information, so much as it is about what data structure would be a good choice. Most folder structures will be of the following (template) form, but it could really end up being anything and any number of subfolders.

```
work
---projects
---assets
------clips
------music
------3d
deliver
---review
---approve
---master
finalize
---VFX
---GFX
```

I originally split up work, deliver and finalize into 3 database tables, but then the client informed these master folders also need to be dynamic. So now I'm really thinking that I will just store every folder and file in the directory, with path as the primary key, in a database table. I'm not sure how to keep my metadata in sync as files move around in the file system. I suspect with UPDATES, instead of just DELETE on the entire table and then INSERTs again which would lose the metadata, but suspect it's achievable.

So what table structure would be good? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just take a look at [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DirectoryInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and emulate them?

Comment: Just to be clear, when you're talking about "files" and "folders" here, you're not talking about the OS filesystem files and folders, but rather how to emulate the file/folder-like structure in SQL Server?

Comment: Erik: FileInfo and DirectoryInfo is what I am using to populate the database... but I want to get the structure right before I get too deep. Sergey: I am not talking about 'emulating' the folder structure in the DB, but rather 'copying' and 'syncing' the structure in the database (without the actual data, which can be accessed by the path stored in the DB). Note this is not the OS drive, but a mounted network drive. Basically the client wants a custom version of windows explorer, but very specialized and able to handle 100TB of project data. First step is generic, filesystem to DB structs.

Comment: Honestly, I've been trying to convience the client not to bring all this data into a DB... rather, use metadata on files and just build a good explorer for the file system. But you apparently can't associate folders with meta data so the client doesn't like that approach. I don't know, I've also considered making one table for folders and one table for files, with paths as the PK. That sounds like a good idea, but I need some experienced input. Maybe I create a new table everytime someone creates one of these 'project' folders defined above.

Comment: The ideal structure, in my brain, is to have one table for every single folder, linked together in a tree like structure truly replicating the file system structure. But that would be a monumental task to program for a dynamic file structure and it may be a very bad idea for all I know. I've been studying these issues for months and have no good approach to solving the problem.

Comment: There really is no good answer with this information. What works best for you depends on what you want to do with your data. An answer needs knowledge of your functional and non-functional requirements.

Answer (score 0):

So, what I understand from reading the question and comments is that you need to keep in your database a list of folders and sub folders that is similar to the OS folders, except you need to add to each folder a property for `folder role`.

Unless I'm missing something, a simple self referencing table should be enough:

```
CREATE TABLE tblFolders
(
    FolderId int identity(1, 1),
    FolderName varchar(100), -- or whatever length that suits your needs
    FolderRole int, -- a foreign key to folder roles table
    FolderParentId int NULL-- a foreign key to reference the current table
    --- what ever else data you might need
)
```

Comment: You've got the right idea. Now consider, you have this table populated with 1000 rows. A user who has this networked path mounted decides to move a folder A, inside folder B using windows explorer. Now the database is out of sync with the real data, so it needs to be refreshed. However, since FolderRole only exists in the database and since there is really no way to tell where the file moved to from the databases perspective, you cannot update that row with the new path, there is no way to identify it. So then you have to clear the table and repopulate it, but then you've lost the FolderRoles.

Comment: Well, perhaps a database solution is not the best choise for this. Maybe you can add a property directly to a folder somehow.